# Changing Parameters of Local Planner, ROS Navigation

Tags: ros, navigation, planner, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial says:

http://wiki.ros.org/base_local_planner

"There are a large number of ROS Parameters that can be set to customize the behavior of the base_local_planner::TrajectoryPlannerROS wrapper. These parameters are grouped into several categories: robot configuration, goal tolerance, forward simulation, trajectory scoring, oscillation prevention, and global plan."

Where can I set/change these parameters?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188265/changing-parameters-of-local-planner,-ros-navigation/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you looked at `base_local_planner_params.yaml` in turtlebot_navigation/param?
This yaml sets some parameters for TrajectoryPlannerROS. Please check it out! I think that this yaml is useful for you.
In case of eband_planner_params.yaml, contents of yaml is following.

```
EBandPlannerROS:

#TRAJECTORY CONTROL
 differential_drive: true
 max_acceleration: 0.5

# velocity limits
 max_vel_lin: 0.6
 max_vel_th: 0.8
 min_vel_lin: 0.1
 min_vel_th: 0.0
 min_in_place_vel_th: 0.0
 in_place_trans_vel: 0.0

# goal tolerance
 xy_goal_tolerance: 0.2
 yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.2

# angular velocity PID
 k_prop_; 0.75

#eband parameters
```

You will need to check more detailed of Parameter by yourself.

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The navigation [RobotSetup Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) describes how to set the parameters to the navigation stack.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can either set them up in your launch file by giving the values. Or you can load yaml config files into your launch file. The similarity between this is explained in more detail in [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/188474/what-does-roslaunch-do-while-loading-yaml-config-files/). It is preferred to use the yaml config file in the case of the base_local_planner due to the large number of params.

And finally, you can also set these params on the command line as mentioned [here](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments)

---

Originally posted by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) with karma: 1133 on 2014-08-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1